# fish shell disable all prompts temporarily

Tags: prompt, fish

I wanted to create a simple text entry system to provide input to a script. I created a helper function:

```sh
function get_input -a prompt var_name -d 'get user input and place it in var_name'
  echo -n "$prompt"
  read --global $var_name
  echo ""
end
```

but I have a fairly lengthy prompt setup, so my `read` prompt looks ugly:

```sh
tsrep prod2 d235108 ~> nsstltlb13 d235108@nsda3bpldv40 ~/.c/f/p/fishdots_notes> get_input 'hello world' charlie
hello world
tsrep prod2 d235108 ~> nsstltlb13 read> bonjour le monde!
```

So I tried to disable the `fish_prompt` function, using a rename:

```sh
function get_input -a prompt var_name -d 'get user input and place it in var_name'
  functions -c fish_prompt fish_prompt_tmp
  functions -e fish_prompt
  echo -n "$prompt"
  read --global $var_name
  echo ""
  functions -c fish_prompt_tmp fish_prompt
  functions -e fish_prompt_tmp
end
```

but it had absolutely no effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` uses its own prompt, and does not call `fish_prompt`.

You can specify the prompt for `read` with an option:

```
read --global --prompt-str="$prompt" $var_name
```

You can also use a real command:

```
read --global --prompt='echo something: ' $var_name
```

Comment: I tried both of these options and they also had no effect

Comment: Got it to work by combining the read option you mentioned with my nasty function rename hack...  Thanks!

Comment: It does look like the erase on the `fish_mode_prompt` fails.  Posting another question.